# Difference of kernels, (basis of a Jordan Block )

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Basis of a Jordan block

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV3Ex.png)

> Given an endomorphism $f$, the basis of a Jordan block of order $n$ has the form $$B=\{v_1,(f-\lambda Id)(v_1),\ldots,(f-λId)^{n-1}(v_1)\}$$
> Where $v_1$ belongs to $(\ker(f-\lambda Id)^n)-(\ker(f-\lambda Id)^{n-1})$

What does this difference of kernels mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's meant to stand for the set-theoretic difference $$A-B=A\setminus B=\{x\in A\,:\, x\notin B\}$$